# How to set gridview within listview item and click on each grid item with uniq posion and click evant

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview

I want to foll list view with image grid date wise.First get Date list of image and then after get image path list of particular date wise image list.and finally I fill list and grid of particular date wise image(No of images and date not fixed),have a look screen shot.
[Date wise images display in Grid View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Jvy.png)

And now my problem is, When I set click listener on image and add check mark image on click then image add in two position, Why I don't know.and second is when I scroll down list view then check mark visible gone.

I want to select multiple image and add check mark image and perform operation like "Delete image" and "Share image"

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lGFo.png)

I call grid adapter of each list item , look my code tell me what's wrong

Custom List View adapter : get View method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View row = convertView;

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    DateSortedImageItem item = getItem(position);

    if (row == null) {

        row = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_date_sorted_image_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder.tv_date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_row_date);
        viewHolder.rowGridView = (GridView) row.findViewById(R.id.gv_row_item);

        viewHolder.tv_date.setText(item.getDate());

        row.setTag(viewHolder);

        gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(context, R.layout.row_sorted_image_gridview_item,
                item.getDateSortedImageList(), position);

        viewHolder.rowGridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    } else {
        row.getTag();
    }

    return row;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_date;
    GridView rowGridView;
}
```

and my grid adapter code is :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sorted_image_gridview_item, parent, false);

    }
    view = convertView;
    final SquareImageView imageView = (SquareImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_test_row_grid_img);

    final ImageView iv_checked = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_checked);
    final ImageView iv_unChecked = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_unchecked);

    view.setTag(arrList.get(position).toString());

    File f = new File(arrList.get(position).toString());
    System.out.println("arrList size >>" + arrList.size());
    Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.fromFile(f)).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_close_black).into(imageView);
```

I just set Grid View image. And now i set imageview click ivent and add check mark then add check mark event two places and scroll down then visible gone also.

What's wrong hear and how to set click event of image view unique. 
Finally I want to design Look like Google "Photos" app. 
Suggest me any example or library:

Answer (score -1):

First you should create a `POJO` as below

```
public class AlbumItem {
    private String headerStr;
    private List<ChildItem> children;

    //getter - setter....
    public class ChildItem {
        private String childName;
        private boolean isSelected;

        //getter - setter.....
    }
}
```

Now use this `POJO` inside your main adapter.

and in the second adapter handle the selection logic means if `isSelected` is true then show `iv_checked` otherwise show `iv_unchecked`.

Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Hope it will help you.